# Cannot access Preferences(My Profile) in odoo 14

Tags: preferences, odoo-14

I am trying to access the Preferences(My Profile) in Odoo 14 to be able to change the user's country. when I try to access the Preferences the following error appears:
`ValueError: Invalid field 'totp_enabled' on model 'res.users'`

Comment: go in apps check if you have auth_totp app installed if yes, update it
if it's not installed then uninstall it (Don't uninstall in Production and check for dependent module)
this module should be installed correctly and update should resolve the module check if your code of odoo community have this module and make sure you have this module  correct path to access these modules